# Treat and Treatment tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed these two tags [treat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treat) and [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment). A glance at this tags, one would think that they are talking about the same thing, Treatment. After looking at the questions in the tags, I realized they are not talking about the same thing.

I propose we rename the [treat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treat) to [treats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treats) in order to avoid confusion, That way It'll be easier to know the meaning.

Also, we should create tag wikis for the two.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but don't see that pluralising it would change anything, in terms of confusion, except it is in keeping with out tag policy. A tag wiki would sort this out

Comment: I set up treats. Treatment I would leave alone, it doesn't really need pluralization.

Answer (score 5):

[treat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treat) should be renamed [treats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treats) for consistency with our general preference for plural nouns (like [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats) and [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs)).  I don't see the value of [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment); on the lone question tagged with it so far, it adds nothing to the [allergies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allergies) tag that's already there.  "Treatment" is a concept that's associated with some other problem -- allergies, illness, accident-recovery, arthritis, etc.  I don't think the general concept requires a tag; use specific tags instead.

Comment: More discussion of [tag:treatment] here: http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/q/577/31

Answer (score 4):

I was just about to make a meta post asking about the treat tag. But since this one already exists I'm going to add my thoughts here. I think that the [treat] tag should be pluralized because it make more sense for tags to be in the plural form I think.

I think that a question tag is an extremely short (mostly one word) summary about what a question is about. So when you tag a question, or search for questions with a tag, what you're doing is saying "This question is about treats" or "Show me questions about treats"

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I think we should have a concerted effort to create tag wikis, this will solve a lot of problems with tagging. We could hold it as a chat event.

Answer (score 0):

[treat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treat) to be changed to [treats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treats) with a wiki to describe it is a palatable reward for a pet, or some such blurb

Comment: separating these out

Answer (score -1):

I am wholly NOT CONFUSED by [treat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treat) (which refers to a snack) vs. [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment) which may refer to a medication or dose.

I recommend making [treatment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment) (which could be used to refer to a flea bath) a synonym of [medication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medication) or [medicating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicating) or something in a similar vein.

Comment: Which _treatment_ can I use to _treat_ my dog?

Comment: What **treat** should I **treat** my dog with?

Comment: @JoshDM If i were to be new to the site and I wanted to ask a question about treatment. Once I type "trea" and treat comes out with treatment, without a tag wiki, I will select "treat" and maybe even both